# ssrs expression or sql on display field

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have a table with 2 columns: `code` and `description` and data like this:

```
code   description
1      abc
2      zxv
3      otp
```

If I use `SSRS` expression, how to display `description` field when parameter code is selected.

Thank you.

Comment: `DESC` is a reserved word in SQL. Avoid reserved words for table and column names.

Comment: =iif(parameters!code = Fields!description.Value, Fields!description.Value)                                                                                            Can you correct this expression? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your expression

```
=iif(parameters!code = Fields!description.Value, Fields!description.Value)
```

You want to compare the CODE Parameter with the CODE field and return the Description field if the expression is **True**. You'll also need to have an ELSE part for what to use when the Expression is **False** - I used an empty string ( "" ).

```
=IIF(Parameters!code.Value = Fields!code.Value, Fields!description.Value, "")
```

Comment: What was the error? The **Error List** should have some details. I don't see anything wrong with the syntax of the expression. Are the field and parameter names correct? Are you using this in a text box?

Comment: I got it, it should =IIF(Parameters!code.Value = Fields!code.Value, Fields! "",description.Value)

Comment: Cool - I was just checking to see what the issue would be.